# Pandas groupby + scikit learn power transformer

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

As a follow up to my question in [Multiple distribution normality testing and transformation in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58805644/multiple-distribution-normality-testing-and-transformation-in-pandas-dataframe), I have found about the power transformer function from scikit learn.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_map_data_to_normal.html

Lets consider the sales in a massive retail network (hundreds of products and thousands of stores) simplified as follows:
- Store 1, Store 2
- Product A, Product B, Product C

I want to detect anomalies in sales levels by running parametric tests which require all the distribution to be normalised.

I tried to make the Power Transformer function work through a group by function to normalise all the distribution as efficiently as possible, to no avail.

The data actually includes some negative values, so I have decided to use Yeo-Johnson parameter that allows for negative values.

I tried the following:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer
yj = PowerTransformer(method='yeo-johnson') 

df['ScaledSales'] = df.groupby(['Store', 'Product'])['Sales'].transform(lambda x: yj.fit(x))
```

This returned an error.
"Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample."

I also tried using it declaring a function using pandas .to_transform() to transform the list of sales values to make it into a dataframe that could be considered as a 2D dataset, but it returned the same error:

```
def scale (x):
    x.to_frame()
    yj.fit(x)
    yj.transform(x)

df['ScaledSales'] = df.groupby(['Store','Product'])['Sales'].transform(scale)
```

Ideally, I want a ScaledSales column added in the dataframe that contains a value scaled by PowerTransformer based on a store + product group by function, normalising the sales distribution for each store + product combination.

As far as I've understood of PowerTransformer, this is something that should be possible, right?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: your `scale` function does not return anything. Try appending `return x`.

Comment: I tried adding return x but got the same error:
Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead

Comment: Try `df.groupby(['Store', 'Product'])[['Sales']].transform(scale)`. Note the double `[[`.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I indeed have a different error message now.
"ValueError: transform must return a scalar value for each group"

Comment: Don’t use transform. Use apply.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your df is like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Store': ['Store 1', 'Store 2'] * 50,
    'Product': ['Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C', 'Product D'] * 25,
    'Sales': [int(x) for x in np.random.randn(100)*10000]
    })

df

      Store    Product  Sales
0   Store 1  Product A  16243
1   Store 2  Product B  -6117
2   Store 1  Product C  -5281
3   Store 2  Product D -10729
4   Store 1  Product A   8654
..      ...        ...    ...
95  Store 2  Product D    773
96  Store 1  Product A  -3438
97  Store 2  Product B    435
98  Store 1  Product C  -6200
99  Store 2  Product D   6980

[100 rows x 3 columns]
```

create your grouped df:

```
df_groupby = df.groupby(['Store', 'Product']).agg(Sales_sum=('Sales', 'sum')).reset_index()
df_groupby

     Store    Product  Sales_sum
0  Store 1  Product A       8696
1  Store 1  Product C      60152
2  Store 2  Product B     -24319
3  Store 2  Product D      16054
```

then reshape your data and normalize

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer
yj = PowerTransformer(method='yeo-johnson') 

data = np.array(df_groupby['Sales_sum'])
reshaped_data = np.array(data).reshape(-1, 1)
print(yj.fit(reshaped_data))
print(yj.lambdas_)
print(yj.transform(reshaped_data))

PowerTransformer(copy=True, method='yeo-johnson', standardize=True)
[0.99939608]
[[-0.21109932]
 [ 1.49251682]
 [-1.31406424]
 [ 0.03264674]]
```